# Getter function on solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

what mistake did I make?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Getter_check {
   uint public data = 50;
   function f() constant returns (uint r)
   {
       r = data;
   }
}

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "./Getter_check.sol";

contract Getter is Getter_check {
    function getval() constant returns(uint getter_value, uint r)
    {
        var obj = new Getter_check();
        getter_value = obj.data();
        r = obj.f();
    }
}
```

When I call `getval()` my expected output is:

```
50
50
```

But the output of the code is:

```
5.239....36e+76
1.721....12e+76
```

Comment: i've tried you code to check it works perfectly how are you compiling calling your fct

Comment: How did u compiled? did you changed Migration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely correct contract code . I tried this on Remix IDE , It gives your expected output .